# Loading order of js files

Tags: javascript, load

I have two .js files and they are added in head tag in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_nr_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_nr_2.js"></script>
```

`script_nr_2.js` has a variable that uses an object of `script_nr_1.js`, but when page loads, it first initialize `script_nr_2.js`'s vars. So this causes an error in `script_nr_2.js` as it tries to init a var with a nonexistent object.

How do I prevent that, and have them be loaded in order?

Comment: merge both .js files into a single one in the correct order.

Comment: the first js file is some library and both files are pretty long, I radher not doing that till I find a good solution.

Comment: *"script_nr_2.js has a variable that uses an object of script_nr_1.js, but when page loads, it first initialize script_nr_2.js's vars."* That doesn't make any sense. `script_nr_1.js` will be run before `script_nr_2.js` is run.

Comment: That is what makes me stuck actually, or is there anything I am missing? Debugger first goes in the second .js file.

Comment: @SercanAltundaş: With that markup, the first script will *definitely* run before the second, provided the first script file is accessible (e.g., not a 404 or whatever). If you're seeing something else, it's not with that markup, or it's observational error (e.g., your breakpoint in the first script is in code that has been set up to run later, such as a "DOM ready" or page load handler).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that markup, `script_nr_1.js` will *always* be run before `script_nr_2.js` (provided, of course, the first script file is actually accessible). If you're seeing something from the first script that isn't ready yet when the second script runs, that means that the first script is setting up some kind of delayed initialization, perhaps waiting for "DOM ready" or page load.

You'll have to delay the execution of any code in the second script that relies on that initialization until it has been performed. You've said the first script is a library; if it's doing this, presumably it has a means for notifying you when it's done. If it doesn't, I'd look for an alternative library.

Comment: The code delay is a good point to start ... I have the same problem actually.